# Canvas Rectangle position

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw

I'm new with the canvas on Android. I'm trying to draw a square at the center of the screen, I want to increase or decrease the size of the square when I click the button. The problem is I don't understand the position of the square.
When I add a code like this it's positioning correctly (5 left and 5 top): `canvas.drawRect(5, 5, sideLength, sideLength, mPaint);`
But I want to draw this square at the center of the screen as I've mentioned before.
I've tried this but the square doesn't appear on the screen: `canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, sideLength, sideLength, mPaint);`

It would be great if you could help me to find a solution for this.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FrameLayout frameLayout;

MyView myView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

    myView = new MyView(this,200);

    frameLayout.addView(myView);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            frameLayout.removeView(myView);
            myView = new MyView(MainActivity.this,600);

            frameLayout.addView(myView);
        }
    });
}
}
```

MyView.java

```
public class MyView extends View {

Paint mPaint;
int sideLength;

public MyView(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public MyView(Context context,int sideLength) {
    super(context);

    this.sideLength = sideLength;

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, sideLength, sideLength, mPaint);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getWidth()/2` and `getheight()/2` will give you the center coordinates of your container.
Assuming your container is a perfect square with dimensions `(2000, 2000) in pixels`, your center coordinates will be (1000, 1000). With this in mind, you are attempting to draw the left side of your square at coordinate `1000` and the top part at coordinate 1000.

Now the next part is where the problem arises. You are attempting to draw the right side at coordinate `600` and the bottom at coordinate `600`

When drawing rectangles and squares, the following should be noted:

1. The right coordinate should be greater than the left
2. The bottom coordinate should be greater than the top.

Below is a working code which draws a square in the center of a FrameLayout

`MyView.java`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {

    Paint mPaint;
    int sideLength;
    PointF center;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, int sideLength) {
        super(context);

        this.sideLength = sideLength;

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(center.x - sideLength, center.y - sideLength, center.x + sideLength, center.y + sideLength, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        int y = getHeight() / 2;
        int x = getWidth() / 2;

        center = new PointF(x, y);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#dedede"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```